# What does this message from Meteor mean?

Tags: html, meteor, handlebars.js

```
I20150915-11:57:51.605(1)? undefined
```

I received this message in the terminal when trying to run a .handlebars file.

The main file seems to be working fine and any changes I make to it are taking effect however when the .handlebars email template loads I get this error.

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

please note that this is a local git repo copy file.

I understand that the 12:10: part is the time that the undefined function or whatever was found.

Thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: I guess somewhere in your code you have a `console.log(<some expression>)`. That expression happened to be undefined.